Execute multiple concurrent (async let) tasks and throw their error only when all of them are failed
For example I need to get 2 arrays of the same type from different sources. Both of these requests may fail but I need to show any error (given by server) when these requests are failed simultaneously.
Here is a common example but it throws an error when any of requests is failed:
func test() async throws -> [Any] {
    async let t1 = getArr()
    async let t2 = getArr2()
    return try await t1 + t2
}

func getArr() async throws -> [Any] {
    []
}

func getArr2() async throws -> [Any] {
    []
}

In the same time if I use try? I lose the error returned by request.
I could also remove throws and replace returning result with Result<[Any], Error> but it looks strange.
How to resolve this issue correctly?

Just to be clear, you want test to throw an error if and only if both getArr and getArr2 throw errors? If only one of them throw an error, then test should return the array that the other method (which didn't throw) returned. Is that right?

And why does suing Result<[Any], Error> "look strange" to you? What else looks strange?

@Sweeper yes, you understood me correctly. Result<[Any], Error> looks strange because I partially avoid throws which is provided by swift concurrency and use a solution from another framework.

Result isn't "another framework". It is part of the Swift Standard Library. This problem requires you to store the caught errors (unless you only need to throw the last error). Even if you don't use Result, you will end up reinventing something similar to it.

You definitely should use Result here. For convenience, first write a Result initialiser that catches errors in an async throwing closure.
extension Result {
    init(asyncCatching block: () async throws -> Success) async where Failure == Error {
        do {
            self = .success(try await block())
        } catch {
            self = .failure(error)
        }
    }
}

Assuming you want test to throw all the errors when all of the async lets threw, make [Error] an Error type too.
extension Array: Error where Element: Error {}

Then it is as simple as:
func test() async throws -> [Any] {
    async let t1 = Result { try await getArr() }
    async let t2 = Result { try await getArr2() }
    switch (await t1, await t2) {
    case let (.failure(e1), .failure(e2)):
        return [e1, e2]
    case let (.success(s), .failure), let (.failure, .success(s)):
        return s
    case let (.success(s1), .success(s2)):
        return s1 + s2
    }
}

For a more general version of this "reducing a collection of Results into a single value or throw" operation, you can write:
func accumulateResults<T, U, Failure: Error>(_ results: [Result<T, Failure>], identity: U, reduce: (U, T) -> U) throws -> U {
    var ret = identity
    var success = false
    var failures = [Failure]()
    for result in results {
        switch result {
        case .success(let s):
            ret = reduce(ret, s)
        case .failure(let e):
            if success { break }
            failures.append(e)
        }
    }
    return if success { ret } else { throw failures }
}


Without using Result (or reinventing something similar to it), test can only throw the last error, because you cannot store any previous errors (the exact job of Result).
func testWithoutResult() async throws -> [Any] {
    async let t1 = getArr()
    async let t2 = getArr2()
    var result = [Any]()
    var success = false
    do {
        result.append(try await t1)
        success = true
    } catch {}
    do {
        result.append(try await t2)
    } catch {
        if !success { throw error }
    }
    return result
}

For every non-final async operation, write do block and set success = true. For the final async operation, if !success { throw error } in the catch block instead.

While Swift concurrency minimizes our reliance on Result types (having its own, more natural, way of throwing errors and returning success), but Result types are still very much supported.
For example, Task has its own result property. So, I might leverage that in this case and return an array of success/failure values:
func test() async -> [Result<[Int], Error>] {
    let t1 = Task { try await getArr() }
    let t2 = Task { try await getArr2() }
    
    return await withTaskCancellationHandler { 
        await [t1.result, t2.result]
    } onCancel: { 
        t1.cancel()
        t2.cancel()
    }
}

func getArr() async throws -> [Int] {
    if Bool.random() {
        return [1, 2, 3]
    } else {
        throw RandomChanceError.badLuck
    }
}

func getArr2() async throws -> [Int] {
    if Bool.random() {
        return [4, 5, 6]
    } else {
        throw RandomChanceError.badLuck
    }
}

enum RandomChanceError: Error {
    case badLuck
}

The only trick with unstructured concurrency is that you bear the responsibility for adding cancelation handling, as illustrated above using withTaskCancellationHandler. (You might not currently anticipate canceling this test method, but it is nonetheless prudent to always add cancelation handling whenever writing unstructured concurrency.)
Regardless, the caller could iterate through these results:

for result in await test() {
    switch result {
    case .success(let value): print(value)
    case .failure(let error): print(error)
    }
}


In your example, you are returning [Any]. Do getArr and getArr2 each really return an heterogeneous array? Or are you using [Any] because the two functions actually just return two different homogeneous arrays of different types?
If the latter is true, I might advise retiring [Any], as that does not actually reflect the nature of the two separate homogeneous arrays. E.g., below, I contemplate a scenario where the first (which I have renamed to getNumbers) returns a homogeneous array of one type and the second (which I have renamed to getStrings) returns a homogeneous array, but of different type:
func test() async throws {
    let numbersAndStrings = try await getNumbersAndStrings()

    switch numbersAndStrings.numbers {
    case .success(let numbers): print(numbers)
    case .failure(let error):   print(error)
    }

    switch numbersAndStrings.strings {
    case .success(let strings): print(strings)
    case .failure(let error):   print(error)
    }
}

func getNumbersAndStrings() async throws -> (numbers: Result<[Int], Error>, strings: Result<[String], Error>) {
    let t1 = Task { try await getNumbers() }
    let t2 = Task { try await getStrings() }

    return try await withTaskCancellationHandler {
        let results = await (
            numbers: t1.result,
            strings: t2.result
        )
        try Task.checkCancellation()
        return results
    } onCancel: {
        t1.cancel()
        t2.cancel()
    }
}

func getNumbers() async throws -> [Int] {
    try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(.random(in: 1...3)))
    if Bool.random() {
        return [1, 2, 3]
    } else {
        throw SomeError.badLuck
    }
}

func getStrings() async throws -> [String] {
    try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(.random(in: 1...3)))
    if Bool.random() {
        return ["four", "five", "six"]
    } else {
        throw SomeError.badLuck
    }
}

enum SomeError: Error {
    case badLuck
}

That eliminates unnecessary typecasting (assuming, again, that you are dealing with two homogeneous arrays, each of a different type).
